# How to programmatically discover the filesystem without mounting the device (like "fdisk -l")

Tags: c++, system, call

I need to find a **system call** in linux to discover the filesystem of a connected pendrive in my application. I found out that the 'fdisk -l' do the job however I need now to discover how this happens. I wasn't capable to discover reading the fdisk code, the only certain think is that:

1. The structs statfs or statvfs are not used;
2. The fdisk doesn't need to mount the device to find the filesystem;

Obs: My application is written in C++ and is running in a embedded linux system.

Comment: The answer in this link explains the structure that contains information you are looking for:  
http://superuser.com/questions/328974/understanding-how-filesystem-type-is-determined-before-it-is-mounted

Comment: Just a note: you do need to mount the device itself (I think 'mount' however is an incorrect term when you refer to the device, but I use it here as you used it yourself). You are probably asking how to do it without mounting the file system that is eventually stored on the device.

Comment: You could do `strace -fv fdisk -l` to see what system calls it's using.

Comment: `fdisk -l` only reports the tag that is assigned to the partition, which is completely distinct from and is not required to match the actual filesystem on the partition, as the link provided by @GermannArlington points out. The manual page for `mount` documents how `mount` tries to determine what kind of file system actually lives on the partition, and it's not exactly simple.

Answer (score 2):

The command fdisk -l displays the file system represented by the **System ID** byte.  This byte is in the Partition Table which is inside the Master Boot Record (MBR).  The MBR is usually stored on the first cylinder on the first hard drive (although any hard drive can have an MBR).

I would think you could simply use the open and read system calls to read the MBR from the disk assuming the user running your program has permission:

```
char buf[446];
int fd = open("/dev/hda", O_RDONLY);
read(fd, buf, 446);
```

Look over the [MBR Format](http://wiki.osdev.org/MBR_%28x86%29) and then read out the partition table to get the System ID bytes.  Here's a [list of types](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html) for the System ID byte.

I am only aware of how fdisk on Linux works, and last time I checked it didn't support GPT or any other partitioning formats.  So this answer is relevant only to the classical MBR format.

Comment: The system ID byte is not enough to reliably detect some filesystems. For example, the value 0x83 is used by several different Linux filesystems.

Comment: @John Bartholomew that is correct.  But the OP asked for results like fdisk -l, which also suffers from this shortcoming..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [libblkid](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.22/libblkid-docs/index.html) from [util-linux](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) to do this. The source distribution includes a sample which lists the partitions on a specified device, including filesystem type.