# Detect a cryptofs device or partition

Tags: linux, encryption

I'm trying to develop an automount for cryptofs encrypted devices/partitions. The thing is that I don't have experience in the low level layer of Linux.

Is there any way I can detect when a cryptofs device or partition has been inserted in the system? (p.e. when you insert a dongle with a regular partition and an encrypted one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never tried but I would follow this approach:

In Linux plug and play is handled by hal and/or udev. hal is bit older and most of the recent distributions uses udev.

You can start looking into "libudev". Using libudev api's you will be able to get the information about connected devices.

This should help: http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

After that, open the device and start reading the filesystem information and figure out if it is cryptofs

See, if this answer helps: [How to programmatically discover the filesystem without mounting the device (like "fdisk -l")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495537/how-to-programmatically-discover-the-filesystem-without-mounting-the-device-lik)

Comment: Thanks, I'll surely take a look at that.